# Angularjs material's md-checkbox not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to implement `md-checkbox` with `ng-model`, `ng-true-value`, `ng-false-value`, and `ng-change`. However, It's not working properly. The value seems to revert back to the original each time when the `ng-change` is fired, as shown here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXawdN#anon-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.cb2` value will be changed by `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` accordingly. You do not need to change the value of `data.cb2` in `myMethod()`. In your implementation, you are reversing the change of value set by `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`. Therefore, the value always revert back to the original value.

Change the part where `data.cb2` value is set and proceed with other processing as seen below.

```
$scope.data.myMethod = function(){
    alert($scope.data['cb2'])
    //other codes and procecssing

}
```

Comment: But, I do need to make the method call, let's say, to perform some other operations.  At the same time, I must use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to display the correct state of checkboxes at the time of loading.

Comment: Ok I understood what point you're trying to make and if I remove the method that will work as expected. However, I do need to perform a certain action on the click of the checkbox. How should I go ahead with that without a method call?

Comment: U can still use the ng-change with myMethod(). Just don't change the value of cb2